# Console.log() not displaying data (AngularJs files)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have couple of doubts

1. Consider this code

'use strict';

```
    foodMeApp.controller('RestaurantsController', function RestaurantsController(
            $scope, customer, $location, Restaurant) {
console.log($scope); //not working
console.log(customer); //not working
console.log($location); //not working
console.log(Restaurant); //not working
        if (!customer.address) {
            $location.url('/customer');
        }
        ...
        ...
    });
```

Firstly i want to know,  Why no console.log working.

2
. I have **batarang** extension in chrome, but looks messy for me. As i am new to angularjs. So can you guys tell me some tips and tricks to debug the code.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this piece of code is being executed?

Comment: Maybe `console.log` is overridden? Eg. `console.log = function(){}`. I had this once in one of my projects.

Comment: The function to controller should be an anonymous function. Remove "**RestaurantsController**"

Comment: Next to what @Sai answered, consider user the `$log` service.